# When quoting books, ought pages be separated as they are on paper?

Tags: quotation

I agree with this [user](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/28524/revisions) that reproducing page breaks make quotes less readable, but I prefer authenticity for whenever I cross-reference the book with the quote:

1. is my preference usual? Are there any famous academics who do this?
2. Or ought I ignore physical page breaks?
3. Is there a term for reproducing page breaks?
4. Is there a term for ignoring physical page breaks?

Comment: I've never seen this before, but I can see how this can be justifiable practice, especially if one is just learning academic writing. Would it be useful to replicate an example here?

Answer (score 5):

No. Unless the presentation of the text is particularly important for some reason (maybe the author is drawing pictures with the way words are arranged), you can assume that the actual content is more important than the choices of font size, margin widths, inter-paragraph separations, title font size... that lead to the exact page breaks that occur in the particular edition you are reading. I don't really see anything "authentic" about reproducing page breaks. The authors was probably not even involved in the choices that lead to these particular page breaks.